# line spacing in dynamically created swift 3/xcode labels

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift3

I'm having an issue where I am getting a list of skills back from an api and I want them to stack one on top of the other in two different sections, a left column and a right column. It works well but if the skill is longer than the width of the label it drops to a new line with the same spacing as the rest of the labels. The skill Adobe Creative Suite looks like Adobe Creative as one and Suite as another. I would like Suite to be underneath Adobe Creative but much closer so you can tell it's all one skill.[image]

My code is here:

```
        lblLeft.text = ""
        lblRight.text = ""

        if let expertiseCount = helper.expertise {
            for i in 0..<expertiseCount.count {
                if i % 2 == 0 {
                    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10
                    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: lblLeft.text! + "\(expertiseCount[i].name ?? "")\n")
                    attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
                    lblLeft.attributedText = attrString

                } else {
                    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10
                    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: lblRight.text! + "\(expertiseCount[i].name ?? "")\n")
                    attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
                    lblRight.attributedText = attrString
                }
            }
        }
```

I've already tried line spacing and that just changes the size between all lines so the space between Adobe Creative and Suite takes on that change as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
lblLeft.numberOfLines = 0
lblLeft.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

lblLeft.sizeToFit()
```

By setting number of lines to zero and turning word wrapping on, the label will grow to the required number of lines.  sizeToFit() should size it properly.